# Solving equation involving polynomial fractions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My problem is $$\frac{2}{x-4} - \frac{3}{x+7} = \frac{22}{x^2+3x-28}$$

I have the LCD as $(x+7)(x-4)$ however I came up with the solution as $6$ but it should be $x=4$ or no solution? Can someone explain?

Comment: It seems you made an error somewhere. If you show your work we can help you spot it.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{2(x+7)}{(x+7)(x-4)}-\frac{3(x-4)}{(x+7)(x-4)}=\frac{2(x+7)-3(x-4)}{(x+7)(x-4)}$$

You can also factor the denominator of RHS as $(x-4)(x+7)$. Can you now cancel the factors in LHS and RHS assuming they are not zero. If your answer comes $-7 \text{ or } 4$.

You have to note that it is not a possible solution as then denominator in question becomes zero.

Comment: One of the denominators in the LHS is $x^2$. You cannot create a polynomial $(x-4)(x+7)$ by multiplying $x^2$ by other polynomials.

Comment: Sorry, I meant RHS.

Comment: @mathh OP meant to use brackets there. It was rather obvious. See edit now in OP.

Comment: I'm surprised he couldn't even bother correcting his equation hours later after an incorrect edit.